# CRichEditCtrl::StreamIn error codes

Tags: mfc, rtf

Does anyone know the meaning of the error codes of `CRichEditCtrl::StreamIn` ?

I use the following code to insert formatted text into my control, and sometimes I get an error code like *-16* back.

```
EDITSTREAM es;
es.dwError = 0;
es.dwCookie = (DWORD) &mf; // mf is a CMemFile
es.pfnCallback = RtfStreamInCallback; // this is my callback

pRichEditCtrl->StreamIn(nFormat,es);
```

After the call to StreamIn, es.dwError = -16. But WTH does that mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error code is the return value from your callback function.

See the section on Return Value in the MSDN entry for EditStreamCallback:

Return value
Type: DWORD
The callback function returns zero to indicate success.
The callback function returns a nonzero value to indicate an error. If an error occurs, the read or write operation ends and the rich edit control discards any data in the pbBuff buffer. **If the callback function returns a nonzero value, the rich edit control uses the dwError member of the EDITSTREAM structure to pass the value back to the application.**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb774368(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: Thank you. I read this documentation at least a dozen times, but always missed this part.